# Getting "fatal: repository not found" when "git clone" a URL

Tags: git, clone

This must be something basic but I can't figure it out. I have a github URL that has the form "https://.../tree/main". How do I download the contents? In response to

`git clone https://.../tree/main`

I get

`fatal: repository 'https://.../tree/main/' not found`

When I do

`git clone https://.../`

I get the contents of the root folder but not the subfolder that I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch --show-current`?

Comment: @DanielB When I do `git branch https://.../tree/main --show-current` and `git branch https://.../ --show-current` I get `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Please don't modify commands. You must run this command in the folder where the cloned repository resides.

Comment: When I do `git branch --show-current` I get the same exact error message. But why would I expect anything else? I am in my local folder that I just created and I am trying to clone the repo for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GitHub HTTPS URL is of the form `https://github.com/OWNER/NAME`, with an optional `.git` on the end.  The URL you're using, with `/tree/main`, is designed to render the `main` branch in the user interface, but that isn't a valid repository and you can't use it with Git.

If it's the case that you want to look at the `main` branch in the repository, then clone it using a proper URL, and then run `git checkout -b main origin/main`, which will create a `main` branch that's a copy of the remote branch.  If you're already on the branch `main`, then that won't work, and you can just look at the repository once it's cloned.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this error also when the repository is empty.

```bash
shell> git clone https://repos.example.org/test_001.git
Cloning into 'test_001'...
fatal: repository 'https://repos.example.org/test_001.git/' not found
```

This means it is not enough to create on the server an empty repository for testing

```bash
admin# pwd
/usr/local/www/repos.example.org
```

```bash
admin# git init --bare test_001.git
```

---

Note: For example, a virtual host in Apache

```bash
admin# cat /usr/local/etc/apache24/extra/repos.example.org.conf 
     <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName repos.example.org
     DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/repos.example.org
     </VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName repos.example.org
     DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/repos.example.org
     SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/repos.example.org.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/ssl/private/repos.example.org.pem
     </VirtualHost>
```

```bash
admin# cat /usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes/usr-local-repos-example.conf 
<Directory /usr/local/www/repos.example.org>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```bash
admin# ll /usr/local/www/repos.example.org/test_001.git/
total 40
drwxr-x---  7 admin  www  512 Jul 22 12:36 ./
drwxr-x---  3 admin  www  512 Jul 22 12:36 ../
-rw-r-----  1 admin  www   23 Jul 22 12:36 HEAD
drwxr-x---  2 admin  www  512 Jul 22 12:36 branches/
-rw-r-----  1 admin  www   66 Jul 22 12:36 config
-rw-r-----  1 admin  www   73 Jul 22 12:36 description
drwxr-x---  2 admin  www  512 Jul 22 12:38 hooks/
drwxr-x---  2 admin  www  512 Jul 22 13:00 info/
drwxr-x---  7 admin  www  512 Jul 22 13:00 objects/
drwxr-x---  4 admin  www  512 Jul 22 12:36 refs/
```

Test the URL `https://repos.example.org/test_001.git/` in a browser. You should see the content of the repo

```
Index of /test_001.git
Parent Directory
HEAD
branches/
config
description
hooks/
info/
objects/
refs/
```

---

Clone the repo locally on the server and commit something. This will also create the branch master. Then, you'll be able to clone the repo over https

```bash
shell> git clone https://repos.example.org/test_001.git
Cloning into 'test_001'...
```

Answer (score 0):

***Alternatively***, the solution could be something simpler than the answers above:

1. Go to the GitHub repo you want to clone
2. 'Fork' the repo to your GitHub account
3. Now, from your machine's CLI, do the *"usual thing"*:

   ```bash
   $ git clone https://github.com/<your account>/<your fork>
   ```

I found this to be necessary when recently trying to clone some repos at the raspberry pi GitHub site.